# Why am I getting a extra dimension when I'm using Numpy's apply along axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, methods

**Using:**
python version 3.10.2, numpy version 1.23.0

```
# Setup
import numpy as np

# functions
def get_RGBA_from_Int(num):
    b = num & 255
    g = (num >> 8) & 255
    r = (num >> 16) & 255
    a = (num >> 24) & 255
    return (r,g,b,a)

def get_INT_from_RGBA(ls):
    r,g,b,a = ls
    num = (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b
    return num
```

## Test Case 1

```
# Convert a 3d array value into a rgba
# 4294967295 == [255,255,255,255] for a RGBA color of white
# Int to RGBA array of (4,)
x = np.zeros((5,5,1), dtype='int64') + 4294967295 # a 5x5 image colored white in array format
output = np.apply_along_axis(get_RGBA, 2, x) # Testing conversion
print(y.shape) # prints to screen :: (5,5,4,1)
# This adds 1 dimension to 3d array
```

## Test Case 2

```
# Convert a 3d array rgba into a int
# 4294967295 == [255,255,255,255] for a RGBA color of white
# RGBA array of (4,) to Int of (1,)
x = np.zeros((5,5,4), dtype='int64') + 255 # a 5x5 image colored white in array format
output = np.apply_along_axis(get_INT, 2, x)
print(y.shape) # prints to screen :: (5,5)
# This removes 1 dimension from 3d array
```

I know I can fix my outputs by reshaping the output array for each "Test Case". However, I'm trying to understand what I'm doing incorrectly. It's odd that I gain 1 dimension on "Test Case 1", and I loose 1 dimension on "Test Case 2".

Comment: First a quick comment about `apply_along_axis` - don't use it if you don't understand it.  It isn't a performance tool.  It isn't worth the effort.

Comment: What do you get with `get_RGBA_from_Int(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

For each value, your first function returns 4:

Give it a scalar:

```
In [5]: get_RGBA_from_Int(1)
Out[5]: (0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Give it a 1d array, and we get a tuple of 4 arrays:

```
In [6]: get_RGBA_from_Int(np.array([0,1,2]))
Out[6]: 
(array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

which made into an array is (4,3) shaped:

```
In [7]: np.array(_).shape
Out[7]: (4, 3)
```

Now define a 2d array - with 1 row:

```
In [8]: x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
In [9]: x.shape
Out[9]: (1, 3)
```

We can use a list comprehension to iterate on rows:

```
In [10]: np.array([get_RGBA_from_Int(i) for i in x]).shape
Out[10]: (1, 4, 3)
```

we can use `apply` to do the same thing:

```
In [11]: np.apply_along_axis(get_RGBA_from_Int, 1, x).shape
Out[11]: (1, 4, 3)
```

With your `(5,5,1)`, it iterates on the (5,5) dimensions, passing each of those 1d (1 element) arrays.  Each call to your function returns a (4,1), to the total result is (5,5,4,1).

`np.apply_along_axis` is intended to work with a function that takes a 1d array as argument.  Your `get_RGBA_from_Int` is designed to work with a single number (returning a tuple).